# Are AJAX Posts 8 bit Clean? / Relation to Base64 / An alternative? / Where is it?

Tags: php, javascript, base64

Base64 only uses 6 bits per character (2^6 = 64) to create textual data from image files.  This causes an in-efficiency.

According to a [wikipedia entry on  Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), this in-efficiency is to protect against 8 bit dirty things like email.

Is Ajax Posting 8 bit clean?  If so, is there an alternative to using Base64?

php.net ( as does wikipedia ) claims a 33% in-efficiency for [base64_encode.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kind of. All JavaScript strings are UTF-16, not byte strings. If you're sending the data with `send`, then it will be encoded into UTF-8 before it is sent. As such, you can convert the bytes into Unicode code points, which will then be encoded into UTF-8. When it reaches the server, you'll have to decode the UTF-8 and then convert the code points back into bytes.

For 7-bit data, this will not expand the size of the data at all. For 8-bit data with the most significant bit always set, it will double the size of the data. For 8-bit data with the most significant bit set half of the time, it will increase the size of your data by 50%, which is worse than the Base64 33.3͞% increase.

On the other hand, using [`XMLHttpRequest` Level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-XMLHttpRequest-20120117/) will allows you to send binary data by passing `send` an [`ArrayBuffer`](http://www.khronos.org/registry/typedarray/specs/latest/#5), [`Blob`](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/#blob), or [`FormData`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-XMLHttpRequest-20120117/#formdata). However, `XMLHttpRequest` Level 2 is only supported in newer browsers.

Comment: Sorry I did not specify but this was for Base64 images on the Server...being sent to the client on initial load.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest Level 2 looks interesting as this is the object I use to retrieve the data from the server (POST Ajax).  But, the encoding is where I want my 33% back.  I need the image in text form b.c. I concatenate it with my CSS....into one BLOB to cut down on my Network requests.

Comment: @Hiro: If I understand you correctly, you're saying you want to retrieve the images with AJAX so that the client can add the images into some CSS so the browser will not have to fetch images referenced from CSS? If so, that's pointless because you've just shifted what does the fetching of images from something inside the browser into your own code; the number of requests will be the same.

Comment: I can concatenate all my text in to ONE request....now I can put all my CSS, JS, HTM, and images into a single request...good idea huh?

Comment: I need a way to encode images to text at 100% efficiency. Where is it!!??

Comment: @Hiro: It's not possible if you want to put *everything* into *one* request and still be compatible with most browsers. You're going to have to have at least two: one for the HTML and a bootstrapping script, and one for the rest of the data. Even then, you may not be able to have 100% efficiency on all browsers, although you could have that on some browsers.

Comment: @Hiro: I should also note that it isn't always a good idea to reduce the number of requests. If you're making a website with a bunch of pages (each of which share resources) rather than, say, a web application all in one page, then it is a bad idea to combine the content and the shared resources as the browser can no longer cache the shared parts.

Comment: It just boggles my mind that web developers are o.k with loosing 33%....very poor implementation of something that could be much better....people want to seem to compare their performance absolutely wrather than relatively...on an absolute level my quess is a performance hit in the uS range...but relatively more likely a few percent or or more.

Comment: @Hiro: I think you're misinterpreting me. It is possible to not increase the size of the data on many browsers, but you are going to have to have more than one request if you want to be compatible with them.

Comment: @Hiro: Additionally, you have not said what type of web site it is: a content-based web site or a web application. As I mentioned before, this affects how you may structure things; if it's content based and you put everything into one request, you would remove all the advantages of caching and end up increasing bandwidth.

Comment: No it won't... I only make the request...if the single request is needed, if the content is new ... it correlates to a new revision of the web-application...I don't want to cache...parts of my web application...I update it and release it as a whole.  This is how I use my cache manager...anyways...way off topic...this post was to find a way to get the 33% back that is lost in Base64 encoding by using an 8-bit clean path way and an efficient coding mechanism that takes advantage of this.

Comment: @Hiro: Okay. If it's a web *application* as you state and not a normal web*site*, then indeed, caching will not help you much. As I have stated before, it is possible in some browsers to not expand it by 33%, but you will have to concede that 33% for the remaining browsers that do not support the techniques.

Answer (score 1):

I think AJAX posting is the same as a generic POST requests in that aspect; that's why we need 'multipart/form-data' for sending files' content, for example. Usually the data gets url encoded, but Base64 is perhaps a better way, as it's (generally) more efficient.

**UPDATE**: It might be helpful to look at this the other way. ) You need some stream of values, that might possibly take all 8 bits, to safely pass the 7-bit filtering. The perfect solution is to use '7-to-8' encoding, so each 7 bytes become 8 'safe' characters. But this is not applicable, as some of these 7-bit characters are actually used to specify some additional (meta) information about the stream...

Now you have a dilemma: either use the next integer (6 bit - that is base64) - or try to invent a scheme with 'non-integer' divider. Such schemes exist (check [Ascii85](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii85), for example), but they are rarely used.

Comment: I believe the 7-bit control characters are safe in `POST` data.

Comment: It's an interesting question actually. ) If POST data is sent with Content-Type set to 'x-www-form-urlencoded', will server take anything not url-encoded (that should be, I mean)?

Comment: And if it's sent with 'multipart/form-data', we shouldn't care about 8-bit cleanness at all, that's what I mean.

Comment: I don't know if the server will take it well, but the client will send it just fine. How the server interprets it is another problem (if it's a problem at all).

Comment: The problem I see with Base64 is that it doesn't use the full character set that it "takes up"...sending text over Ajax is already error checked...but the text you send with Base64 only uses certain characters...a-z,A-Z,0-9, and a few more....it is a very superficial limitation....if someone would just fix it or point me in the direction of a library that converts the character set so all the other characters are included .  Excluding characters..amounts to throwing bandwidth away...very not good thing to do...as an extreme example this would be like sending Morse Code over Ajax requests.

Comment: Each character would only be sending one bit....0/1 on/off...when it takes up 8 bits.

Comment: I need a way to encode images to text at 100% efficiency. Where is it!!??